# Python Selenium WebDriverWait for element to be visible not working as intended

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to pick up an element based on its xpath and wanted to use WebDriverWait however it doesnt seem to be picking the element up -

When I use -

```
abc = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[2]/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]').text
```

I get the result as intended -

```
abc
```

'-624,917.42'

However for the same xpath when I use the following (which is what I want to put in the final script), it returns no output -

```
xyz = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[2]/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]'))).get_attribute("value")

xyz
```

No output

```
print(xyz)
```

'None'

I have also tried the 'visibility_of_element_located' variant with no luck.

Can someone please point out the obvious error I am making here?

Comment: Try with relative xpath

Comment: I dont think the xpath itself is the problem since its able to locate the element if I dont use webdriverwait

Answer (score 1):

This works -

```
xyz = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[2]/ag-grid-angular/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[4]'))).text
```